# Weird object issue when trying to render partial from mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, mailer

Using Rails 3. Per first snippet of code below, it's hard to google search what this error means when trying to render a partial from my mailer view.

This is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `long_date' for #<#<Class:0x00000102452ab0>:0x00000102440b30>):
```

Here's my mailer view (email_note.html.erb)

```
<div style="width:500px;">
  <%= render :partial => "shared/note", :object => @note %>
</div>
```

This is the call i'm making in my partial that is throwing the error
    <%= long_date(note.created_at) %>

long_date has always worked when I have given the partial @note objects from other actions (e.g. 'show' in my notes_controller). this is the method

```
def long_date(date)
  date.strftime('%A %b %e, %G')
end
```

Here is my ActionMailer class (address and note_id are sent from an 'email' action in my notes_controller)

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default :from => "gminett@gmail.com"

  def email_note(address,note_id)
    @note = Note.find(note_id)
    mail(:to => "#{address}", :subject => "Note from repository: #{@note.subject}")
  end
end
```

Seems to me rails (very most likely due to some oversight on my part) is not interpreting my @note object as a Note class, but i don't know how to fix it. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default ActionMailer templates don't share the same helpers that ActionView ones do. If you need to use helpers in your mailer templates then try including the module in your ActionMailer class:

```
include DateTimeHelper
```

Comment: When I add include DateTimeHelper just below my

Comment: ...(hit enter too fast) class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base i get the following error: NameError (uninitialized constant UserMailer::DateTimeHelper):

Comment: You'll most likely have to require the file above the mailer. Does that work?